# Trouble loading data into Tableview from firebase

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Having an issue loading my data from firebase database into my tableview.

I have the following. UItableview controller, CollegeDetailVC (which acts as a form that essentailly fills out the tableview controller), individual model for a singular "Offer", and an OfferCell which is the tableviews custom cell

Basically I want to fill out a form, send the data of that form to firebase and reload the tableview with said data from particular user. I am recieving the data in a print statement but nothing on my tableview. I'm Sorry if this is all rather trivial, but I have been stuck for sometime and any advice will be greatly appreciated. Sorry in advance for stupid mistakes, and let me know if this could be more clear. thankyou!!

```
Model - Offer.swift

class Offer: NSObject {

var college : String?
var headCoach: String?
var email: String?
var skype: String?
var notes: String?
var state: String?
var uniqueId: String?

}
```

TableView Controller.. that contains a list of offers of a certain User

```
 import UIKit
 import Firebase

 class MyOffersVC: UITableViewController{


var offers = [Offer]()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    loadData()
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.offers.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OfferCell", for: indexPath) as? MyOfferCell
        cell?.titleLabel.text = offers[indexPath.row].college
        cell?.subtitleLabel.text = offers[indexPath.row].headCoach


    return cell!


}

//to get it back to contact form!. in here we need to load all info for selected row into the detailVC
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let detailVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CollegeDetailVC") as! CollegeDetailVC
    detailVC.offer = offers[indexPath.row]
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)
}





@IBAction func newItemPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {



}



func loadData() {
    self.offers.removeAll()
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("Users").child(uid!).child("MyOffers").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if let offerDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
            for (_,offerElement) in offerDict {
                print(offerElement)
                let offer = Offer()
                offer.college = offerElement["college"] as? String
                offer.headCoach = offerElement["Headcoach"] as? String
                offer.email = offerElement["Email"] as? String
                self.offers.append(offer)
                print(offer)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                     self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }

        }




    } 




}

 }
```

The Form style VC

```
CollegeDetailVC

import UIKit
import Firebase

class CollegeDetailVC: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, 
UIPickerViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var collegeField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var headCoachField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var skypeField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var notesField: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var statePicker: UIPickerView!

var details : MyOfferCell!

var offer: Offer?
let statesArray = ["Alabama","Alaska","Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado","Connecticut","Delaware", "Georgia", "Florida", "Hawaii","Idaho", "Illinios", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true


    self.statePicker.delegate = self
    self.statePicker.dataSource = self
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if self.offer != nil {
        collegeField.text = self.offer?.college
        headCoachField.text = self.offer?.headCoach
    }

}





@IBAction func savePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    if offer == nil {
        offer = Offer()
    }


    offer?.college = self.collegeField.text
    offer?.headCoach = self.headCoachField.text
    offer?.email = self.emailField.text
    offer?.skype = self.skypeField.text
    offer?.notes = self.notesField.text


    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let key = ref.child("MyOffers").childByAutoId().key

    let dictionaryOffers = ["College" : offer?.college,
                            "Email" : offer?.email,
                            "HeadCoach" : offer?.headCoach,
                            "Skype" : offer?.skype,
                            "Notes" : offer?.notes]

    let childUpdates = ["Users/MyOffers/\(key)": [dictionaryOffers]]
    ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) -> Void in

        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

    }) 

}
```

}

OfferCell

```
 class MyOfferCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var subtitleLabel: UILabel!

}
```

firebaseDatabase structure  here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EUdX.png)

[image: debugger even though data is there its not being passed into my model]

Comment: "cell?.titleLabel.text = offers[indexPath.row].college " here college is a string or object of Offers ?

Comment: It’s an optional string @NaumanMalik

Comment: make sure cell outlet is connected properly and with check points in CellForAtIndex make sure you got data after  table reload, you may try with some static text.

Answer (score 1):

```
cell?.titleLabel.text = offers[indexPath.row].college
cell?.subtitleLabel.text = offers[indexPath.row].headCoach
```

In your database, you dont have values for key **college** or **Email** which you are trying to parse in loadView method[image].

In your firebase response, you get these values:
**abc123**,
**L6wb_mGe7BJyWVPhriP**

Please check in database. Add it manually if these keys are missing there, you should be able to find your tableView with data.

**Note that if you are trying to push any object to firebase and the value (say for emailId) is nil, it will not be created in backend.**

So make sure you are sending a value to your email key else it wont be visible in firebase

Comment: still printing out in the debugger the results but not connecting to my outlets.. Even have three seperate rows of data which I entered just no labels.. I dont know if its an issue with the outlets or not I have checked them all and they are connected? also when selected row there is no info in the collegedetailVC

Comment: did u give constraints to your label? Also, print the main array after your for loop operation before you reload the table. Check if the dataource is having your newly appended values

Comment: As of yet no .. I have it on GitHub if you would like to take a look ?

Comment: also Im thinking it could be my database structure? in my load data im trying to bring down the current users offer.. which i have just hard coded in for test data at this point by referencing it to it in the database with the autoID and simply adding true. in the Users node.. you can see above in the screenshot.

Comment: If it was ur structure, u shouldnt have got the values you said were printed earlier

Comment: Can u give me credentials which has data for MyOrders

Comment: tester123@hotmail.com ... 1234567

Comment: those numbers that u see are the "offers" that Im trying to take from the database.. thats why I believe its something wrong with my structure.. I don't know how to relate the MyOffers section of the database to the individual user ? I simply put the autoID made when the offer is saved under a user an set value to true (thats why its coming up with 1)..

Comment: To link offers with user, the first section of the image you shared was right. MyOffers/userID/autoID. Then use the userID to get your offers. Putting it inside user object doesnt make sense

Comment: I have been looking at this for a decent amount of time so I dont waste your time. And I managed to implicate what you told me above^ and also using the answer you provided me. I am now getting a snapshot of all the values or the current users offer but as soon as I get to setting the model data it isnt passing through.. I will include a screenshot in the edit. Your answer helped me alot thankyou!!!! It got me in the right direction.

Comment: Hi  a couple of days have passed an I am printing the data.. But still I cannot see the results from the database in my cell.. help please. I am struggling. @zzzz

Comment: Hi @TarshadeSouza is there a way to share your fire base credentials? Or give me access so that I can see what’s actually happening

Comment: if you send me your email I can give you access via firebase as a collaborator. :)

Comment: Also have the latest commit to git hub. After seeing your answer I fixed alot of things so now it is printing to the console.. https://github.com/tarshadesouza/SpainSports/tree/FirebaseSetup

Comment: I haven’t got access to firebase

Comment: I figured it out eventually :D thankyou for your help anyhow :) I had to pull the data in different than all the documentation I read. But eventually I figured it out. @zzzz

Answer (score 0):

You are using UITableViewCell "Subtitle" style on your **OfferCell** prototype cell on Main.storyboard which has their own label implementation.

You have two options here:

1) Use the default implementation of "Subtitle" cell style: (textLabel and detailTextLabel are default labels for the "Subtitle" cell style).

```
// Change this lines of code:
  cell?.titleLabel.text = offers[indexPath.row].college
  cell?.subtitleLabel.text = offers[indexPath.row].headCoach

// With this ones:
  cell?.textLabel?.text = offers[indexPath.row].college
  cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = offers[indexPath.row].headCoach
```

2) Use a custom implementation of cell style:

[image: Custom cell style]

This way, your outlets will take place into your custom cell.

**Note:** 
Using this implementation will delete your titleLabel and subtitleLabel from your cell, you will need to add them again and apply the corresponding constraints.

Hope this will help you.

O.M.